# Интеграция API Транспортной служки себе на сайт JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, api

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом могу интегрировать к себе на сайт в оформление заказа Список городов и отделений с этого [сайта](https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/556d885da0fe4f08e8f7ce46) . Формат Json, я не имею понятия как это все сделать. За любые подсказки буду очень благодарен!!!

Comment: Создал API ключ, вставил куда просят. Но дальше не знаю как интегрировать Выбор городов и отделений себе на сайт!

Comment: Необходимо сохранять список городов и отделений себе в Базу данных. Получить список можно Curl-ом на PHP, недавно делал, могу помочь

Comment: Был бы очень благодарен за помощ. Хочу с транспортной службы взять этот спмсок городов и отделений через API

Answer (score 0):

```
/*CONNECT DATABASE*/
$mysqli = new mysqli("/*Адрес*/", "/*login*/", "/*password*/", "/*Имя базы данных*/");

if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}


if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) 
{
    printf("Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
}
/*END CONNECT DATABASE*/

/*ОТПРАВКА ЗАПРОСА*/
function sendRequestNP($application)
{
    $url = "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/";
    $application = json_encode($application);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $application);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($application))
    );
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response = json_decode($response, true);
}

/*СПРАВОЧНИК ГОРОДОВ КОМПАНИИ*/
function locality($KeyAPI)
{
    $application = array(
        "apiKey" => $KeyAPI,
        "modelName" => "Address",
        "calledMethod" => "getCities"
    );

    return sendRequestNP($application);
}

/*СПРАВОЧНИК ОТДЕЛЕНИЙ И ТИПОВ ОТДЕЛЕНИЙ*/
function offices($KeyAPI)
{
    $application = array(
        "apiKey" => $KeyAPI,
        "modelName" => "Address",
        "calledMethod" => "getWarehouses",
        "methodProperties" => array(
            "Language" => "ua"
        )
    );

    return sendRequestNP($application);
}

$KeyAPI = "/*API ключ*/";
$response = locality($KeyAPI);
if($response[success] == '1')
{
    /*Очистить Таблицу*/
    $truncate = "TRUNCATE TABLE NovaPoshta_cities";
    $mysqli->query($truncate);
    foreach($response[data] as $city)
    {
    /*Добавить в таблицу новые записи*/
    $insert = "INSERT INTO NovaPoshta_cities (Description, DescriptionRu, Ref, Area, SettlementType, SettlementTypeDescription, SettlementTypeDescriptionRu) VALUES ('".$city[Description]."', '".$city[DescriptionRu]."', '".$city[Ref]."', '".$city[Area]."', '".$city[SettlementType]."', '".$city[SettlementTypeDescription]."', '".$city[SettlementTypeDescriptionRu]."')";
    $mysqli->query($insert);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я сейчас проверю как работает и отпишусь!! Спас ибо!

Comment: Эти функции на страницу оформления заказа добавить? А как в базу данных добавить список городов ? Можно конкретнее что и зачем? Плохо понимаю ))

Comment: 1). В базе данных создайте таблицу к примеру "NovaPoshta_cities" 2). Создайте файл с любым названием, который нужно будет запускать по расписанию раз  в день. 3). В созданный файл вставляете весь код выше

Comment: В таблице строки Description, DescriptionRu, Ref, Area, SettlementType, SettlementTypeDescription, SettlementTypeDescriptionRu

Comment: Так добавить в базу данных "Города компании", "отделения" так же. Если будет не понятно пишите, отвечу завтра.

Comment: Ок, сейчас буду делать. Отпишусь если что то не будет получаться!

Comment: Зашел в БД. Создаю несколько файлов:wp_nova_poshta_city (Список городов), wp_nova_poshta_region (Список областей), wp_nova_poshta_warehouse (Список отделений). Что делаем дальше ?

Comment: Как с тобой можно держать связь? у меня есть вайбер +380934173552 или почта hulkcoffee@gmail.com напишешь мне ?)